# How can I check to see if a forward history exists in Javascript? (Disabling back button)

Tags: javascript

Got a `window.history.go(1)` to stop the user hitting the back button, but was wondering if I could check to see if a forward history exists before doing it, so I can display a popup warning the user not to press the back button.

I know you can get the history length, but is there a way to get the current position in the history list? Or some other way of doing this...

Comment: If you think you need to break the back button your site is doing something very wrong on a basic level, that you should try to fix instead of wasting time on this.

Comment: Oh absolutely, it's a nasty hack for a much bigger problem, but if you want to rewrite the 60+ pages of legacy code I've been dumped with for a priority task that is flagged as "emergency" then be my guest ;)

Comment: Send your emergency taskmasters to this page. Maybe they'll see the light.

Comment: Disabling the back button or attaching an alternative handler to its functionality has a perfectly acceptable use case when using fragment identifiers for navigation within a page. This is especially true in a web app where sections of a page are loaded instead of whole pages. I realize the comment by @bobince is old and things were different then, but saying it's _wrong on a basic level_ to do something different when the back button is clicked was never true. Even in '09, it depended on the situation and use case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AFAIK you won't be able to access the history from JavaScript. It will be a security hole and most of the browsers won't allow that. Probably there might be a workaround in IE by using ActiveX.

Found this entry which might be useful to you

[window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history)

There is a **next** property.

> Returns the URL of the next item in
>   the session history 
>   This property is not available to web
>   content and is not supported by other
>   browsers.
>
> For security reasons the History
>   object doesn't allow the
>   non-privileged code to access the URLs
>   of other pages in the session history,
>   but it does allow it to navigate the
>   session history.
>
> There is no way to clear the session
>   history or to disable the back/forward
>   navigation from unprivileged code. The
>   closest available solution is the
>   location.replace() method, which
>   replaces the current item of the
>   session history with the provided URL.

Comment: Yeah it does look that way, but it's also confusing that it would let you get the number of items in the list and stuff like that.

Comment: In response to your edit, I don't see how it is a security hole to be able to check if a function you wish to call will succeed or not...

Comment: Its not about a function call, but its about the user security being exposed to an unknown website.

Answer (score 5):

For Chromium based browsers, check [`window.navigation.canGoForward`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/navigation#cangoforward)

Answer (score 0):

Don't break the back (or forward) button.

1. You don't know exactly what they might do without knowing every possible user's setup (including plugins, etc.)
2. You still have to do something mildly intelligent (e.g. not trash your database) if scripting is disabled, or disabled then re-enabled, etc.
3. Because you already have to handle #2, don't even worry about figuring out how to do #1 everywhere for everyone, and spend more time to make #2 work better.
4. Now your site works with the back button.